# Duplicate a control on two windows on two screens

Tags: wpf, screenshot

I need to duplicate a control on two windows on two different screens, I am writing a WPF application in which I have a "WebBrowserControl", I need to duplicate the "WebBrowserControl" onto another window and on another screen. I need to render exact copy on both screens, moreover I need to capture mouse movement on both screens. Mouse should be moving at exact locations on both screens.

Can anyone suggest anything? I have tried capturing screen and putting it in another window, but how do I capture mouse movement?

Any ideas? Any help will be of great value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the mouse move event is the answer on how to capture mouse movement.

[MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemove)

The part that confuses me is how you are going to have a mouse on both screens.